# word describing name and birthday collectively

Tags: nouns, collective-nouns

i'm looking for a word that would exclusively denote the person's name and birth data

it should be analogous with words such as **contacts** denoting entities such as **email**, **phone number**, **address** perhaps, that can be often seen in cv's, or **credentials** which is another collective word for **username** and **password**

Comment: Would the expression [personal details](https://www.google.com/search?q=Personal+details&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=DOR6VJeLBInVat6fgMAP&ved=0CB4QsAQ&biw=1366&bih=653) be suitable?

Comment: well, i'm afraid not, it seems to be a phrase, and it may have broader definition, including other details as well not limiting in the entities i stated above. so basically i don't think it is suitable for its non-exclusiveness

Comment: It has to be one word, so what about *details*? But I doubt you'll have a one word expression which covers name, surname and DOB. The term *contacts* doesn't necessarily denote emails, home addresses, phone numbers etc. Is this word for computer programming?

Comment: no it's actually for cv, but i just want to group those words on my mind :) it can be more than one word, but it should indicate only those fields, or at least be less narrower than [personal details](https://www.google.com/search?q=Personal+details&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=DOR6VJeLBInVat6fgMAP&ved=0CB4QsAQ&biw=1366&bih=653)

Comment: Those two fields have no particular relationship one another, so there is no standard word or phrase which groups them together, without also admitting other concepts.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no single word** whose meaning encompasses name and birthdate.

Comment: ....... Source?!

Answer (score 1):

In government circles, Name, Date of Birth, Sex, and sometimes other attributes, are often referred to collectively as 'Identity Set'.

Answer (score 0):

"i'm looking for a word that would exclusively denote the person's name and birth data." This question was asked November 30 2014.

The word he is looking for is the word "demographics." Does that answer the question sufficiently?

Comment: Hello, Meredith. The 'data' sense of 'demographic' is actually defined as 'Noun 1. demographic - a statistic characterizing human populations (or segments of human populations broken down by age or sex or income etc.). This does not match OP's request, being far too general. {[Based on WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/demographic)}

Answer (score 0):

You could colloquially use "**Stats**", an abbreviation of statistics. Of course this can be used to represent much more information than specifically name and DOB, but they do fall within the umbrella that this can cover.

> [Statistic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statistic) - a number that represents a piece of information